# Devise 302 infinite redirect after password reset sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In a Rails 6 app, I am using the [Devise gem](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) (version 4.9.3). In the development environment, when I try to reset a password, the outbound email is sent, but then I get a 302 redirect resulting in an infinite loop of redirects:

> Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in Completed 302 Found
> in 7022ms (ActiveRecord: 12.8ms | Allocations: 31198)
>
> Started GET "/users/"

I tried to override the Passwords controller and set the redirection path but  same issue:

```
def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  root_path
end
```

I tried disabling caching, cleared the cookies / session, but I still get the error.

Maybe it comes from the User model, where I disabled password validation in order to create users without password (they add their password after confirming their email).

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :skip_password_validation

  has_secure_token
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable

  protected

  def password_required?
    return false if skip_password_validation
    super
  end
end
```

Where does this issue come from? I am out of ideas… Thanks for your help!

This issue only happens in Development environment and concerns all Devise POST requests (the redirection loop also happens after creating an account, signing in/out etc.).

Comment: what's your root path?

Comment: The root path is /, there is no difference if the user is logged in or not.